# Xcode 4.6 how to assign the text of a label to an NSString variable

Tags: xcode, text, nsstring, label

I have an app that has a label in an xib, which contains text.  I would like to assign the text to an NSString for use in other areas of the View.  My attempt to accomplish this is:

- In the xib, select the label, show the Identity Inspector, and under Document, fill in the Label field with the desired label name - example: mylabelname
- In the .m file, of the same name as the xib, inside a method, assign the value of the label to the variable, example: mytextfield

  NSString  *mytextfield =[mylabelname.text];

I get an error on the above - Use of undeclared identified 'mylabelname'.

From my research, I think I want to do something like this in my label:

```
[label mytextfield: mylabelname.text];
```

Or something similar, but I am not sure how, or where.  Can anyone provide me some pointers or guidance on this?  I bet this is simple, but I have not been able to figure it out.

Thanks!
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSString *myString = myLabel.text;`

Your problem is enclosing this in `[]`'s

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately, it seems there is still something wrong - I remove the brackets, and I still have the error: Use of undeclared identified 'mylabelname'  There must be something I am supposed to do to further define the name of the label.  When I expand the Document Outline, under Objects, the label item does show up with the name (ie: mylabelname) that I defined in the Label field under the Document section in Identity Inspector.  Since my name shows up under Objects, I would think that the label name is set properly, but there must be something more...

Comment: Replace 'myLabelName' with the name you assigned to the outlet of the label you want the text of.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have what you are recommending in place:
 - Label field of the Label shows "mylabelname", and that is what shows up in the Document Outline for the label item
 - Using: NSString *mytextfield = mylabelname.text;
   Still see the error.  hmmm

Comment: Not yet, I still have the : Use of undeclared identifier 'mylabelname'   I must not be assigning the label name properly

Comment: In the .h equivalent of the file you are putting this code into, what is the text between the `*` and the `;` on the line with the `@property` corresponding to the label?

Comment: Sorry, this must be what I have done wrong,  I do not have the label defined in the header .h file.  I will see if I can figure that out, this must be what I am missing

Comment: I guess in .h, I put in the UIViewController { IBOutlet UILabel *mylabelname;}

Comment: No more error!  In the .h, I set up the IBOutlet UILabel *mylabelame in the UIViewController.  In the .m, I created a -(void)mylabelname { NSString *mytextfield = mylabelname.text; }  Lastly, connected the Lable outlet to the Label in the xib, and I think I got it!  Thanks for tipping me off on the .h equivalent of the file that needed coding!

Answer (score 2):

Any one will work

```
NSString *mytextfield =[mylabelname text];
```

or,

```
NSString *mytextfield =mylabelname.text;
```

Comment: Thanks Anoop, I think I am not assigning the name of the label properly somehow...

Comment: Have you hooked the UILabel to the IBOutlet called mylabelname?

Comment: Thanks Anoop - no, maybe this is the missing piece?  Where do I set that up?

Comment: open your xib and .h file. ctrl+drag from the UILabel to .h file and hook them up.

Comment: check this answer, this may come handy althuogh this is for osx but very similar to ios too. [Hooking to outlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629515/is-there-a-simple-cocoa-application-tutorial-with-explanation/15629664#15629664)

Comment: No more error!  In the .h, I set up the IBOutlet UILabel *mylabelame in the UIViewController.  In the .m, I created a -(void)mylabelname { NSString *mytextfield = mylabelname.text; }  Lastly, connected the Lable outlet to the Label in the xib, and I think I got it!  Thanks for tipping me off on the xib hookup!

Comment: I want to select both of these responses as an answer, since I had to change the xib, and the .h file.  I don't think I can mark them both as an answer, but each response was valid.

Comment: Hi Anoop, your responses were a necessary component of this solution - hooking up the UIlabel in the xib.  The other pieces of the solution were to fix that I did not have the IBOutlet UILabel *mylabelame entry in the .h, and I also figured out that I needed to set up the .m with -(void)mylabelname { NSString *mytextfield = mylabelname.text; }.  I've got apps on the App Store, but there is still a lot that I do not know, and this is probably one of those basic things!  But I did like your response, and wish I could mark both of these responses as an answer!